# JavaScript mins and seconds into seconds

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string being grabbed from a page in the format "4m 26s", how can I strip this into just seconds?

Many thanks,

Comment: What result are you looking for: `26s` or `266s`?

Comment: Looking for 266, as in 4*60+26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "4m 26s";
var arr = str.split(" ");
var sec = parseInt(arr[0], 10)*60 + parseInt(arr[1], 10);
```

You don't need regex if you use parseInt...

Answer (score 3):

Simple regex will work:

```
var s = '21m 06s';

var m = /(\d{1,2})m\s(\d{1,2})s/.exec(s);

var mins = parseInt(m[1], 10);
var secs = parseInt(m[2], 10);
```

Comment: This is a silly comment; you could technically say regexes are always unnecessary. It solves the problem as requested. I could downvote your answer saying that using split is unnecessary.

Comment: no, here regexp is slow, harder to read and harder to maintain, thus overcomplicates the problem. you should use regexp when you have a good reason for it. you could've edited your code but you're rather arguing with me.

Comment: Slow? Care to back that up with some numbers? I think you'll find there's little to no difference in terms of performance.

Harder to read and harder to maintain are subjective, especially since it's a small and easily readable regex. Just because you aren't comfortable with it, doesn't make it complicated.

Again, stupid comment.

Comment: why is it so hard to admit there is a better way? happens to everyone... *"it's easy to make things bigger, it's hard to make things better..."*

Comment: I like how you ignored everything I said. Nice one ;)

Answer (score 2):

A non-regex way:

Do a `string.split(" ")` on your string; then do `string.slice(0, -1)` on both arrays. Multiply the first entry by 60. Add them together.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "4m 26s";
console.log(str.match(/\d+m\s+(\d+)s/)[1]);//26
```